# SketchUp Ruby API - ArgumentError when delete all layers

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I made a script to delete all layers imported from a .dwg file:

```
# import the dwg file
show_summary = false
if Sketchup.active_model.import file_path, show_summary

    # delete all layer
    protected_layers = ['Layer0', '! 3D', '! AutoCad']
    10.times do
        Sketchup.active_model.definitions.purge_unused
        Sketchup.active_model.layers.purge_unused

        Sketchup.active_model.layers.each { |layer|
            layer_name = layer.name
            if not layer.deleted? and not protected_layers.include? layer_name  
                puts "\tdeleted"
                Sketchup.active_model.layers.remove layer
            end
        }
    end
end
```

When I import a big dwg file, all layers are not instantly imported (more or less 100 layers)... So I added a `10.times` loop to all layers are completly removed. My script work perfectly until there are 10 layers left. I got an error like this:

```
Error: #<ArgumentError: layer doesn't belong to this model>
```

So how to check my layer is not already deleted? I tryed theses solution but no one seem worked

- `layer.deleted?` not return `true`
- `layers.at layer.name` not return `nil`
- `begin;rescue;end` around the loop **crash** Sketchup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating the collection you are removing elements from. That is never a safe thing to do.

Cache the layers to an array an iterate that.

Here is an example:

```
model = Sketchup.active_model
# Map layer names to layers - as object comparison is much faster than string
# comparisons.
protected_layers = ['Layer0', '! 3D', '! AutoCad'].map { |layer_name|
  model.layers[layer_name]
}
# Start an operation as this keeps the undo stack clean and makes the script
# fun faster.
model.start_operation('Remove Layers', true)
model.layers.to_a.each { |layer|
  next if layer.deleted? || protected_layers.include?(layer)
  model.layers.remove(layer)
}
model.commit_operation
```

Comment: is the code between [`start_operation`](https://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/model#start_operation) & [`commit_operation`](https://www.sketchup.com/intl/en/developer/docs/ourdoc/model#commit_operation) launching at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by that? The start/commit methods wraps up the model changes into a single undo item in the undo stack. But there is no concurrency in the code between them.

Comment: Is the mistakes was that I work directly on `layers`? Is a simply `layers.to_a` resolve it because `to_a` copy all layers in a "static" array?

Comment: Yes, any time you need to remove something for a collection you need to work on a cached copy because the iterator will get out of state when you add/remove items.
This isn't just a Ruby thing, but in most programming languages in general.

Answer (score 0):

I founded a solution with `Sketchup.active_model.layers[l.name].nil?` wich prevent with layers already removed. Here the sample of my solution

```
layers.take_while{|l| not l.deleted? and not layers[l.name].nil? }.each { |layer|
    puts layer.name
    unless protected_layers.include? layer.name  
        puts "\t[*] deleted"
        layers.remove layer
    else
        puts "\t[ ] undeleted"
    end
}
```